# Div under another absolute variable height div

Tags: css

I have a div with variable height (only an image with max-width:100% and auto height to scale it on resize).

So I would like to have a div with text overlaping this image div... Ok. But then I would like to have other div under this wrap with image..

Here's the problem.. I don't know the height of the div ('cause it deppends on the image height on resize) and then, when I try to continue the other divs that should be under this wrap, the get stucker under it 'cause its position is absolute!

```
<div id="wrap">

    <div id="background">

        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/hXtf2Dq.jpg" class="myImage" />            

    </div><!-- #wf_sliderItemBackground -->

    <div id="mySubtitle">

        dfdf

    </div><!-- #background -->

</div><!-- #wrap -->

<div>
I CANT MAKE THIS DIV APPEAR UNDER THE IMAGE... I CANT USE DIMENSIONS SINCE I'M TRYING TO CREATE A RESPONSIVE LAYOUT AND USING HEIGHT IN PIXELS WOULD RUIN IT...
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }

#wrap {

    width:100%;
    display:table;
    text-align:center;

}

#background {
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}

.myImage {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

    #mySubtitle {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100%;
    max-width:1200px;
    background:green;
    position:relative;
    }
```

Check the fidddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cjd6n0mm/

Answer (score 0):

Since your `text div` is outside the `wrap` div, `wrap` should be `relative` with a `height` defined

```
#wrap {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
    height:50%
}
```

and cover your text div in specific div

```
div.a {
    color:blue;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Also, instead of hard reset `*`, use `html,body` reset, thats a *rule of thumb*

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cjd6n0mm/1/)

Comment: But the problem in this solution is:
When I try to resize, upper resolutions will overlay the text and lower resolutions will show a big blank space between the image and the text div! :(

Comment: can you use media queries for this to target viewport width??